# Restart/Stop/Start services via Nagio

Tags: nagios

I'm wondering if it is possible to use Nagios Core to restart, stop, or start services that are being monitored.  I can't seem to find this answer anywhere using google or on any youtube videos.  If you can restart, stop, or start a service, is there any sort of documentation that you know of?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event handlers. Event handlers have many use cases. For example, you can:

- Restarting a failed service
- Entering a trouble ticket into a helpdesk system
- Logging event information to a database
- Cycling power on a host
- etc..

Good and handy documentation you can find here: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagioscore/docs/nagioscore/3/en/eventhandlers.html